# Thunderbolt -> DVI on EVGA

Tags: 16.04, dvi, thunderbolt

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and I have a Thunderbolt 2 screen. I'm trying to connect it (via a Thunderbolt to DVI) to my EVGA GeForce GTX 1070).

I didn't have any success with that, can someone guide me on how to do this?

Comment: Note: I am Using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: If you need hardware recommendations (adapters) this isn't the place. If you're sure the adapter you're using works (in an different OS, for example) then it *might* be an Ubuntu problem. So, please [edit] and define  "haven't any success with that", i.e., what have you tried already, what was expected to happen and what happened instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it was working intermittently with Windows, and not at all with Ubuntu. then intermittently with Ubuntu too. I ended up buy a new PSU which solved the issue.